# Como converter String em Array de Bytes e vice-versa?

Tags: xml, web-service, http, delphi-7

Preciso enviar um XML via post, mas segundo a documentação do serviço, é necessário que o dado seja enviado "em bytes". Então, tenho o XML em questão dentro de um TStringList. Como transformá-lo em um array de bytes? Alguma idéia?
Agradeço qualquer ajuda, abraços!

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/string-para-byte-e-byte-para-string-delphi/18056 Mas não creio que seja isso que você precisa. O diálogo com webservice é por texto mesmo (XML, json, base64...) e não por "array de bytes".

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo! Realmente, já fiz comunicação via webservice outras vezes. Mas infelizmente, nesse caso, é isso. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Tem algum link para a documentação, pq provavelmente será necessário transformar em UTF8, mas isso precisa ficar claro